# Is it even worth picking up weapons in the campaign?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I've been through the first couple of chapters of the campaign, while constantly picking up and trying out any weapon dropped by enemies. So far, I haven't found a single weapon that was noticeably better than the ones I started with. In fact, most were distinctly worse.

So I ask to the members who have already finished the campaign: were there moments in the game were you picked up a weapon that was undoubtedly better than your original one? Was there a pickup, at any point, that made you glad you were picking up everything? Or should I just give up trying out every new weapon I find?

Comment: I'm not sure it applies here exactly, but in the older CODs(think 2 and 3 on the Playstation 2) I would pick up different weapons because it'd be hard to find ammo for the guns that I was provided with at the beginning

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't pick up a second weapon beacuse its better then my first.  I grab weapons so I can build an arsenal to deal with any situation.

For instance, if I'm doing a sniper mission the first thing I will do is replace my sidearm with the first shotgun, smg, or assult rifle I found.  Carrying multiple guns gives you the versatility to always have the appropriate gun for the appropriate situation.

Finally, don't forget that its faster to switch weapons then it is to reload.  Carrying a second gun you enjoy can make your charge 2x more awesome!

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I swap my secondary with enemies' weapons. Note that, they have very little ammo left in them, most probably around 100 rounds, whereas the gun you started with will have something like 500 rounds. It would be a bad idea to replace the primary.

And, if the secondary is a sniper (e.g. the mission in Africa, where Price, Soap and Yuri go to *do stuff*), you might need it later in the mission. Swapping it wouldn't help. Although in MW3, I found another sniper when I was required to do some sniping. This wasn't the case in MW2.